# Scala: how do I access a `Numeric` type's arithmetic operations?

Tags: scala, numeric, implicit

```
class Foo[T](t: T)(implicit int: Numeric[T]) {
  val negated = -t
  val doubled = t + t
  val squared = t * t
  // ...
}
```

I get red squigglies on all three lines here. What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an instance of `Numeric[T]` for some `T`, and this is where all the goodies are. So you simply need to access your desired methods (e.g. `plus`):

```
class Foo[T](t: T)(implicit int: Numeric[T]) {

  val sum = int.plus(t, t)

}
```

If you use a context bound (the "T : Numeric" syntactic sugar), then:

```
class Foo[T : Numeric](t: T) {

  val sum = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(t, t)

}
```

If you want to use the shortcut operators such as `+`, you can simply import the members of your implicit instance:

```
class Foo[T](t: T)(implicit int: Numeric[T]) {

  import int._
  val sum = t + t

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an import for the implicit conversion for those functions:

```
class Foo[T](t: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]){
  import num._
  val negated = -t
  val doubled = t + t
  val squared = t * t
}
```

Because in reality they are defined like this ([scala source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L216-L219))

```
class Ops(lhs: T) {
  def +(rhs: T) = plus(lhs, rhs)
  def *(rhs: T) = times(lhs, rhs)
  // etc
}
```

---

You could also ditch the implicit conversion and do this instead:

```
class Foo[T](t: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]){
  val negated = num.negate(t)
  val doubled = num.plus(t, t)
  val squared = num.times(t, t)
}
```